# ratemyprofessors' alternatives for francophone or German-speaking countries

Tags: professorship

Are there some equivalent/alternatives for the sites like ratemyprofessors.com for francophones or German-speaking countries?

Comment: Are you sure you can't use that site? Some UK schools are there, at least.

Comment: Since it says in the "location" drop-down, "I'm looking for a school in" and the only options are US states or territories (including DC), my guess is it wouldn't be worth trying to hack it for that.

Comment: To the original poster: This is a legitimate question, but ... be careful what you wish for!  It's not exactly scientific.

Comment: @kcrisman Cambridge UK has some listings. It may be possible to add universities outside the English speaking world. But they would be hard to find as the UI seems to limit to the US. But searching for a university seems to work. Also, as a prof, I found it useful even when I was occasionally blasted there. Other students will come to your rescue if untrue things are said. But, yes, not scientific.

Comment: @Buffy thanks, I wasn't aware there were any others there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Germany, there is meinprof.de.